# Error when compiling with MinGW

Tags: c, compilation, mingw

I am trying to compile a hello world program using MinGW on Windows 10. I am compiling from the command prompt with just:

```
gcc hlw.c
```

However, I get the following error:

```
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpthread
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Obviously, my program does not use threads; it should just print one line to the output. What is going wrong?

Comment: Superficially, it looks as if MinGW's GCC always links with the POSIX threads library, but the loader/linker can't find the library.  That suggests that maybe the installation is not complete, or is flawed in some way.  Have you ever been able to compile anything with this set up?  I'm guessing not — this is your initial test.  Check whether your MinGW installation of GCC worked, and whether you have all the necessary support packages (POSIX threads, for example) installed.

Comment: The MinGW installer is quite tedious to use. There is a lot of POSIX-related stuff available for installation, and I installed most of it. Now my program compiles and works fine. However I am still bothered by the fact that gcc always wants to link to the threads library, and the fact that the corresponding libraries are not part of standard MinGW installation. Thanks!

Comment: I've never used MinGW (I used Cygwin when I had a Windows machine), but it is surprising that the necessities were not installed automatically. You could try adding `-v` to the compiler command line to see what it does in detail.

Comment: Good idea! It indeed does
    --enable-threads=posix